# ¿Cómo conectar una aplicación C# a una base de datos Access a través de Internet?

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos, visual-studio, ms-access

He realizado un pequeño sistema de turnos en una clinica, donde los médicos acceden desde una aplicación hecha en C# a una base de datos Access local a traves de LAN.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que la aplicación se conecte a la base de datos Access a través de Internet?

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia. Sigue el [tour] y revisa [ask] para que conozcas lo básico sobre este sitio y la forma de realizar preguntas en él.

Comment: Estás haciendo 2 preguntas en una sola, te sugiero que las separes en 2. Pero además las dos debes reformularlas y ser mas específico con lo que quieres, porque están demasiado amplias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes compartir la base de datos Access a través de Internet de distintas maneras:

- A través de una unidad de red (los clientes deberían tener acceso a la misma red a través de Internet, por ejemplo, a través de una VPN)
- A través de un sitio de Sharepoint
- A través de un servidor de base de datos (como SQL Server Express, o MySQL, y conectando el fichero Access local a dicha base de datos con "tablas vinculadas")

En este enlace encontrás más información: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-b7f250cc-5413-4fc4-a54a-8e2b54db252c